# IFTTT - Download a list of files from a URL

Tags: zapier, ifttt

I have a CSV with a list of file names in the first column

filename1

filename2 etc

The actual files are sitting on website.com/< filename >.pdf

How do I write an applet to download all the files from the URL into maybe Dropbox?

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easy in Zapier

create a Zap that is triggered for new rows in a google sheet, and when triggered reads a cell in the row (which is the file url) and uploads it to dropbox.

Once you have set this up you paste your CSV into google sheets and voila!

Comment: Wow! Thanks. Didnt know that